# Filtering out objects by a specific object in that value

Tags: swift

So I have a list of objects lets say sneakers for example. I get these objects by parsing JSON data. Below is the model class that I use to perform that task.

```
@objcMembers class SneakerInfoTemp: Object, Decodable {
//    dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString

    //list of dynamic properties that will be deserialized from the json and then passed into realm
    dynamic var brand: String?
    dynamic var category: String?
    dynamic var colorway: String?
    dynamic var currentdescription: String?
    dynamic var designer: String?
    dynamic var imagesrc: String?
    dynamic var maincolor: String?
    dynamic var name: String?
    dynamic var nickname: String?
    dynamic var price: String?
    dynamic var productlink: String?
    dynamic var productlinkhref: String?
    dynamic var releasedate: String?
    dynamic var silhouette: String?
    dynamic var technology: String?
    dynamic var webscraperorder: String?
    dynamic var webscraperstarturl: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case brand, category, colorway, designer, imagesrc, maincolor, name, nickname, price, productlink, productlinkhref, releasedate, silhouette, technology,webscraperorder,webscraperstarturl,currentdescription
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        //sneaker information that will be decoded
        //made optional due to the fact that some fields don't exist with every shoe
        brand = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .brand)
        category = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .category)
        colorway = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .colorway)
        currentdescription = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .currentdescription)
        designer = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .designer)
        imagesrc = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .imagesrc)
        maincolor = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .maincolor)
        name = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        nickname = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .nickname)

        price = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .price)
        productlink = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .productlink)
        productlinkhref = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .productlinkhref)
        releasedate = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .releasedate)
        silhouette = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .silhouette)
        technology = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .technology)
        webscraperorder = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .webscraperorder)
        webscraperstarturl = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .webscraperstarturl)
        super.init()
    }


    required init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }

    required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema)
    {
        super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
    }

    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema)
    {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
    }


}
```

When everything is said and done I get a list of objects. The issue at hand is that some of the objects are duplicates. I tried to use a set to remove them but the set can't tell the difference between the objects. I kinda want to take this List of objects and add them to the set based off of some property, lets say the name

I want to do something like this

```
   let objectSet = Set((sneakersTemp.sneakers?.brands?.adidas.map { $0.name })!)
        print(objectSet.count)
```

It returns all unique names but is there anyway for me to get all the unique objects as well.

Comment: User `.filter` instead of `.map`

Comment: Then base equality on the name

Comment: yeah but will it give me back the objects? or just the names again

Comment: @ielyamani can you show me an example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove duplicates by using a `Set`, the type should conform to `Hashable`.

To simplify things, let's suppose the `SneakerInfoTemp` class is defined like so:

```
class SneakerInfoTemp {
    let name: String
    let price: Double

    init(name: String, price: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
}
```

Let's conform to the necessary prorocols:

```
extension SneakerInfoTemp: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: SneakerInfoTemp, rhs: SneakerInfoTemp) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}

extension SneakerInfoTemp: Hashable {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}
```

So given an array of sneakers :

```
var array = [SneakerInfoTemp(name: "a", price: 1),
             SneakerInfoTemp(name: "b", price: 2),
             SneakerInfoTemp(name: "a", price: 3),
]
```

You can create a set of unique elements by using a Set:

```
let set = Set(array)
```

Comment: will try this as well

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter` instead of `.map`. Try this

```
let array : [Obj] = sneakersTemp.sneakers?.brands?.adidas
let filtered = filterUnique(array: array)
```

where `Obj` – your Class/Structure for `sneakersTemp.sneakers?.brands?.adidas` array (or its superclass wtih **var name : String**)

```
func filterUnique(array : [Obj]) -> [Obj] {
    var filtered : [String] = []
    let objectSet = array.filter({ obj -> Bool in
        if filtered.contains(obj.name) {
            return false
        }
        filtered.append(obj.name)
        return true
    })
    print(objectSet.count)
}
```

Comment: going to try this now. if it works ill accept answer

Comment: How is it going?

Comment: the case you put is that specific to my example or now

Comment: because objsetSet still contains all the values when I use your code

Comment: what is your conditions to filter?

Comment: I want it to not be added to the set if there is an object in there that has the same name as it

Comment: have any ideas by any chance?

Comment: i have changed an answer to your case